# Поиск пересекающихся вхождений: крах функции count

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, count

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вернуть количество вхождений одной строки в другую. Задача простейшая, и я намеревался решить ее функцией `count()`. Все, кажется, идет нормально:

```
>>> 'abcdefabc'.count('abc')
2
>>> 'aaa'.count('a')
3
>>> 'abca'.count('a')
2
```

И тут вдруг:

```
>>> 'catcatcat'.count('catcat')
1
```

По идее, `count()` должна возвращать количество вхождений подстроки в строку. Получается, что она возвращает количество *непересекающихся* вхождений.

Вопрос: как быть в случае, если нужно вернуть общее количество вхождений, вместе с пересечениями? То есть, чтобы последний пример возвращал `2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Регулярное выражение:

```py
len(re.findall('(?=catcat)', 'catcatcat'))
```

Ответ взят с английского SO: [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences/11706065#11706065).

Там предложено еще несколько решений.

Comment: О, спасибо, то что надо)

Comment: Вопрос: как это сделать за *N + M*. Все решения до сих пор за *NM*.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Был какой-то алгоритм, который позволял сразу побольше сдвинуться в случае несовпадения паттерна, но я подробностей не помню. Можно модифицировать для совпадений тоже. По-моему в LZ или LZW упаковке он использовался для поиска строк, с которых можно скопироваться.

Answer (score 3):

[Из документации Python `str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

> Возвращает количество **непересекающихся** вхождений подстроки sub в
> диапазоне [ start , end ]. Необязательные аргументы start и end
> интерпретируются как в нотации среза.
>
> Если sub пуст, возвращает количество пустых строк между символами,
> которое равно длине строки плюс один.

Следовательно

```
>>> 'catcatcat'.count('catcat')
1
```

---

А чтобы проверка учитывала пересечения, можно реализовать следующий метод:

```
def count_overlapping_substrings(main_string, substring):
    count = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = main_string.find(substring, start)  # Ищем следующее вхождение подстроки
        if start == -1:
            break
        count += 1
        start += 1  # Перемещаемся вправо, чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла при пересечениях
    return count

# Примеры использования:
print(count_overlapping_substrings('abcdefabc', 'abc'))  # Вывод: 2
print(count_overlapping_substrings('aaa', 'a'))  # Вывод: 3
print(count_overlapping_substrings('abca', 'a'))  # Вывод: 2
print(count_overlapping_substrings('catcatcat', 'catcat'))  # Вывод: 2
```

---

Есть еще такой однострочник

```
import re
count = re.subn('(?=catcat)', '', 'catcatcat')[1]
print(count)
```

Comment: Вы выиграли, удалил свой ответ.

Comment: А через регулярки можно? А то я хотел однострочник написать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, мне казалось, в регулярках какой-то флаг есть, который включает пересечение в поиске паттернов?

Comment: `sum(1 for i in range(len(s)) if p == s[i:i + len(p)])`.

Answer (score 3):

За время `N+M` c использованием z-функции. Линейное время пригодится при работе с немаленькими размерами строк. Для поиска образца длиной 20000 в 200000 - время 0.36 с против 31 c у регулярок.

К образцу `pattern` приписывается символ, отсутствующий в обеих строках, и строка `s`, в которой ведётся поиск. Если значение z-функции в каком-то месте совпадает с длиной образца `lp`, то найдено вхождение (суффикс, начинающийся в позиции `i`, совпадает с префикcом длиной `lp` - а этот префикс и есть образец)

```
def cntoverlapped(s, pat):
    cnt = 0
    ps = pat + '$' + s
    lp = len(pat)
    n = len(ps)
    z = [0]*n
    l = 0
    r = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if (i <= r):
            z[i] = min (r-i+1, z[i-l])
        while (i+z[i] < n) and (ps[z[i]] == ps[i+z[i]]):
            z[i] += 1
        if (i+z[i]-1 > r):
            l = i
            r = i+z[i]-1
        if z[i]==lp:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

print(cntoverlapped('ababababa', 'aba'))

>> 4
```